# Working out the future date with minutes variable

Tags: php

say i have a variable integer of `3000`

Which equates to `3000 minutes`, how would i work out the date from now, to `3000 minutes` into the future?

If it helps, i do have some php which has already broken it down into the variables

```
$days
$hours
$minutes
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is:

```
$minutes = 3000;

$newDate = new DateTime("now + {$minutes} minutes");
echo $newDate->format('m/d/Y H:i:s')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have tried all of the answers i have gotten for this question and they all work well, but for the pure reason that your seems the simplest, i think yours is the one i will go with. Thanks

Comment: All the answers here are good and equally valid. It ultimately comes down to what _your_ code calls for.

Comment: Actually, "now" isn't necessary. `"+{$minutes} minutes"` works as well.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming PHP >= 5.2.0:

```
$d = new DateTime();
$future = $d->add(new DateInterval("PT{$minutes}i"));
                                               ^-- i/m(i)nutes, h/hour, d/day
echo $future->format('c');
```

Comment: Or : $d->modify('+3000 minutes'); DateInterval was actually added in 5.3.

Comment: @evert: that'll work, but then you might as well just use strtotime(). personally I hate resorting to that function. it works well enough in most cases, but blows up spectacularly when it doesn't.

Comment: I'm getting a date in the year 2262, but 3000 minutes is only 50 hours. I think you want `PT{$minutes}M`.

Comment: woops. my bad. `M` is actually months. for minutes, it should be `i`. fixed up the answer text. those date format characters always trip me up

Comment: @MarcB Having done a ton of datetime (caldav/icalendar) work, it's actually pretty reliable. You just need to know the rules. I prefer this syntax over yours, but just because if you're not gonna re-use DateInterval, it's just an extra step.

Comment: it's reliable when you've got reliable inputs. but feed it `01/02/03` and `01-02-03` and watch the general destruction.

Comment: @Marc: You're thinking of typical date formatting which uses _i_. [If the duration contains time elements, that portion of the specification is preceded by the letter T](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php).

Comment: `new DateInterval("PT{$minutes}M")` makes M=minutes. It's a confusing format that seems to defy logic. Ah good ol' PHP. :D

Comment: Yeah. bleah. and it's monday to boot, so I'm functionally brain dead.

Comment: Don't blame it on PHP! it's fully based on ISO 8601

Comment: @Evert: fair enough, but then why do we use "i" to show the minute component in the `date()` function?

Comment: Sorry, this was in reference to the Interval syntax. Unrelated to the syntax of date() and strotime. This is a pretty solid overview though: http://de.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime('+3000 minutes')` will give you the timestamp 3000 minutes in the future.  You can use that timestamp to format with dates.

Alternatively, you can use the `DateTime` class to do the addition with the `add` method, but I think it that's a bit more verbose than what you need.

Comment: OOP does tend to be more verbose in general, but the DateTime family of classes go a long way to over come **many** of the problems that people often run into when dealing with time. (e.g. timezone changes, day light savings, etc.)